# Ways to order a pizza?

Tags: combinatorics

There's 2 pizzas that you're buying, UP TO 3 toppings each, 7 toppings to choose from. Repeat toppings are allowed. Same pizzas are also allowed. Order of pizza or toppings doesn't matter.

How do I do this? I know how to do it for non-repeat toppings but no clue on how to do double or triple toppings.

Comment: $3$ opportunities to pick toppings, $8$ choices each time, since no topping is also a choice, divided by the possible permutations among the topping choices (so that the order won't matter)

Comment: I'm doing $1+ (7) + (7*7 / 2!) + (7*7*7 / 3!)$ but am getting a decimal. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You cannot simply do $\frac{7*7}{2!}$ to remove the repeats because some of those have $2$ of the same topping! $7*6$ combinations of $2$ different toppings can be divided, but you'll need to add the repeats later.

Comment: 'aipzz', 'aizpz', 'aizzp', 'apizz', 'apziz', 'apzzi', 'azipz', 'azizp', 'azpiz', 'azpzi', 'azzip', 'azzpi', 'iapzz', 'iazpz', 'iazzp', 'ipazz', 'ipzaz', 'ipzza', 'izapz', 'izazp', 'izpaz', 'izpza', 'izzap', 'izzpa', 'paizz', 'paziz', 'pazzi', 'piazz', 'pizaz', 'pizza', 'pzaiz', 'pzazi', 'pziaz', 'pziza', 'pzzai', 'pzzia', 'zaipz', 'zaizp', 'zapiz', 'zapzi', 'zazip', 'zazpi', 'ziapz', 'ziazp', 'zipaz', 'zipza', 'zizap', 'zizpa', 'zpaiz', 'zpazi', 'zpiaz', 'zpiza', 'zpzai', 'zpzia', 'zzaip', 'zzapi', 'zziap', 'zzipa', 'zzpai', 'zzpia'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, work out how many types of pizzas you can order *individually*. Treat "no topping" as an eighth type of topping, then the number of pizzas possible is
$$\binom{8+3-1}3=120$$
Now our situation is equivalent to drawing two numbers from 1 to 120 (corresponding to the pizza types) without regards to order but with repetitions allowed. The number of ways to do this is
$$\binom{120+2-1}2=\binom{121}2=7260$$
Hence you can order the two pizzas in 7260 ways.

Comment: Where did you get the 3 and 1, 2 and 1 in the combinations. What do those represent?

Comment: @Krio I am using stars and bars (multisets) arguments for this one. (It's a very powerful idea - go look it up on Wikipedia or elsewhere!) The number of ways to select $k$ elements from an $n$-element set without regards to order but with repetitions allowed is $\binom{n+k-1}k$; the 1's merely appear in the formula. The 8 stands for the 7 toppings plus the "no topping" I devised as a hack. The 3 stands for the maximum number of toppings you can have. The 2 stands for the number of pizzas you order.

Comment: By the way, you wrote the 2000000-th post on M.SE!

Comment: @Watson - and now, I cannot underestimate my accomplishments.